# Dompdf generating blank pages between pages

Tags: html, css, codeigniter, dompdf, html-to-pdf

I'm doing a landing page in Codeigniter where user registers for an event. When user registers, tickets (for the event) are generated in pdf format for the registered person as well as the people accompanying him/her. Number of accompanying people can vary according to the no of seats chosen by the registered person. The problem here is that there are white spaces between pages in pdf (tickets). How can i remove those white pages. I'm using html to pdf conversion using dompdf.

This is my controller:

```html
$passids = $this->Website_model->get_pass_id($REFID);
foreach($passids as $key)
  {
     $campaign_lead_ref_no1 = $key->campaign_lead_ref_no1;
     $data['campaign_lead_ref_no1'] = $campaign_lead_ref_no1;
  }
$html = $this->load->view('website/goldenpass', array('passids' => $passids), true);
$output = $this->pdf->createPDF($html, 'mypdf', false);
```

This is my view page (ticket)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
<title>Golden Pass</title>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
   @page 
   {
        size: 3.94in 9.83in landscape;
        margin-top:0;
        margin-bottom:0;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right:0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #certbackground
    {
        position: relative;
        height:380px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
foreach($passids as $key)
{
?>
<div id="certbackground" >
<?php echo '<img src="'.FCPATH.'/assets/pass/goldenpass.PNG" style="height:380px;z-index: -1;position: absolute;"><h4 style="color:#fff;position: relative;margin-left:115px;margin-top:135px;">'.$key->campaign_lead_ref_no1.'</h4>';?>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my output pdf :

[image]

Comment: Already asked question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518964/dompdf-generating-pdf-in-with-many-blank-pages-between-content

Comment: @BoominathanElango it doesnt solve my problem. Tried.

Comment: i suggested you to check that link